# Wait for all channels to receive and inform about completion using select

Tags: go, concurrency

I would like to define a function that waits for an unknown number of channels to receive and then informs another channel called `allDone` about the completion.

I'm not sure how to list `select` cases programmatically either, some pseudo code might look like this:

```
func waitFor(channels ...chan bool, allDone chan bool) {
    for {
        select {
        case <-channels[0]:

        ...

        case <-channels[len(channels)-1]:
            allDone <- true
        }
    }
}
```